# spork on Win XP/ruby1.8.7 not recognized gem 'win-32process'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, spork

I'm having a real hard time getting my environment ready with rspec and spork.
I am working on an application both on windows and linux environment (linux:home, windows:work)
I had a project configured using rspec and spork at home, when trying to replicate the gems needed for this project to run, I get the following error when trying to install spork.

```
gem install spork

Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing spork:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/bin/ruby.exe mkrf_conf.rb
Actually, there aren't any native extensions. I'm just dynamically installing de
pendencies based off of your operating system
installing windows dependencies
Failed to install necessary dependency gem win32-process: Could not find a valid
 gem 'win32-process' (~> 0.6.1) locally or in a repository


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
/gems/spork-0.8.4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/spork-0.8.4
/ext/gem_make.out
```

I am really frustrated since I have already installed win32-process in the correct version. If I run

```
gem list

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.5, 3.0.4)
actionpack (3.0.5, 3.0.4, 3.0.0)
activemodel (3.0.5, 3.0.4, 3.0.0)
activerecord (3.0.5, 3.0.4)
activeresource (3.0.5, 3.0.4)
activesupport (3.0.5, 3.0.4, 3.0.0)
arel (2.0.9, 2.0.8)
autotest (4.4.6)
autotest-growl (0.2.9)
autotest-rails-pure (4.1.2)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.10)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
erubis (2.6.6)
hoe (2.9.1)
i18n (0.5.0, 0.4.1)
json (1.5.1 x86-mingw32)
json_pure (1.5.1)
mail (2.2.15)
mime-types (1.16)
minitest (2.0.2)
nokogiri (1.4.4.1 x86-mingw32, 1.4.4
open4 (1.0.1)
pg (0.10.1)
Platform (0.4.0)
polyglot (0.3.1)
POpen4 (0.1.4)
racc (1.4.6)
rack (1.2.2, 1.2.1)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-test (0.5.7, 0.5.4)
rails (3.0.5, 3.0.4)
railties (3.0.5, 3.0.4, 3.0.0)
rake (0.8.7)
rake-compiler (0.7.6)
rb-readline (0.4.0)
rexical (1.0.5)
rspec (2.5.0)
rspec-core (2.5.1)
rspec-expectations (2.5.0)
rspec-mocks (2.5.0)
rspec-rails (2.5.0)
rubyforge (2.0.4)
rubygems-update (1.6.2)
rubyzip2 (2.0.1)
sqlite3 (1.3.3 x86-mingw32)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
sys-proctable (0.9.0 x86-mswin32-60)
test-unit (2.2.0)
thor (0.14.6, 0.14.4, 0.14.0)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.25, 0.3.24, 0.3.23)
win32-api (1.4.8)
win32-open3 (0.3.2 x86-mingw32)
win32-process (0.6.1)
windows-api (0.4.0)
windows-pr (1.1.3)
ZenTest (4.5.0)
```

any ideas?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem using milhouse-spork instead of spork itself
this version is, as said on the wiki page, for enabling windows machines to use spork
https://github.com/Milhouse/spork/wiki